# Parenthesis and curly brackets not working as expected in cron

Tags: shell, cron, subshell

I have set the following crontab for the root user:

```
root@curie:/usr/home/username # crontab -l
# /etc/crontab - root's crontab for FreeBSD
#
# $FreeBSD: release/10.0.0/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/config/chapter.xml 43126 2013-11-07 16:37:11Z gabor $
#
#
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
#
#minute  hour  mday    month   wday    who     command
#
41       13    *       *       *       root    ( /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --tables sessions --no-data --single-transaction ; /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --ignore-table rt5.sessions --single-transaction ) | /usr/bin/gzip > /home/username/rt-db-backups/rt-`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d`.sql.gz
```

The job appears to run, but the expected file `rt-20210916.sql.gz` is not created:

```
# ls -la rt-db-backups/
total 5392
drwxr-xr-x  2 username    username        512 Sep 16 13:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 username    username        512 Sep 15 14:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root        username    2693630 Sep 16 10:25 rt-20210915.sql.gz
```

I tried to investigate by checking the logs at `/var/run/cron` but it suggests the command is running:

```
# tail /var/log/cron
Sep 16 13:40:00 curie /usr/sbin/cron[7387]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
Sep 16 13:40:34 curie crontab[7390]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep 16 13:40:42 curie crontab[7390]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Sep 16 13:40:43 curie crontab[7390]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep 16 13:41:00 curie /usr/sbin/cron[876]: (root) RELOAD (tabs/root)
Sep 16 13:41:00 curie /usr/sbin/cron[7396]: (root) CMD (root    ( /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --tables sessions --no-data --single-transaction ; /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --ignore-table rt5.sessions --single-transaction ) | /usr/bin/gzip > /home/username/rt-db-backups/rt-`/bin/date +%Y%m%d`.sql.gz)
Sep 16 13:41:32 curie crontab[7403]: (root) LIST (root)
Sep 16 13:44:00 curie /usr/sbin/cron[7406]: (operator) CMD (/usr/libexec/save-entropy)
Sep 16 13:45:00 curie /usr/sbin/cron[7415]: (root) CMD (/usr/libexec/atrun)
```

It seems the `()` and `{}` notation does not work in cron?

How can I write a cron command that is effectively the same as:

```
( /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --tables sessions --no-data --single-transaction ; /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --ignore-table rt5.sessions --single-transaction ) | /usr/bin/gzip > /home/username/rt-db-backups/rt-`/bin/date +%Y%m%d`.sql.gz
```

Note that I tried the following, which also did not work:

```
{ /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --tables sessions --no-data --single-transaction ; /usr/local/bin/mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 rt5 --ignore-table rt5.sessions --single-transaction ; } | /usr/bin/gzip > /home/username/rt-db-backups/rt-`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d`.sql.gz
```

Comment: The file `rt-20210915.sql.gz` seems to be timestamped on `Sep 16 10:25`.  What timezone are you in?  I'm thinking the timestamp generated is in UTC.

Comment: crontab is not the good place for scripting. I think, it's better to put your line(s) in a shell script file and execute it with cron. It's better for debug, modifying...

Comment: It looks like you are using the format appropriate for an /etc/crontab file (including the extra "who" field) inside root's user crontab. See for example [/etc/crontab or crontab -e as root](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/etc-crontab-or-crontab-e-as-root.4107/). That's why the log is showing `CMD (root    ( /usr/local/bin/mysqldump ...` instead of `CMD ( ( /usr/local/bin/mysqldump ...` I think.

Comment: if it's what steeldriver said, it should give you an error somewhere. About the invalid syntax with the parens, or the command `root` being not found. Did you check the emails cron sends?

Comment: Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Answer (score 1):

@steeldriver was correct.  I was using the wrong format, as /etc/crontab is different from root user's crontab (which does not contain who field).